# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 10001: Connection refused DOCKER

Tags: docker, curl

I start my docker container with:

```
docker run -it --expose 10001 --expose 8080 -p 10001:10001 -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 --rm lucchi/covid90/100e
```

My docker -ps then has:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                                  NAMES    
1521e0c3d947        lucchi/covid90/100e   "/bin/sh -c /bin/bash"   2 seconds ago       Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10001->10001/tcp   funny_panini
```

But I can't connect to localhost from inside the container. I tried:

```
curl 0.0.0.0:8080 
curl 127.0.0.1:8080
curl https://localhost:8080
```

but keep getting

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Most of the asnwers I read are about adding -p to the run command, I don't get what I'm missing.

Comment: That `docker ps` output suggests your container is running a shell and not a server process.  Can you include your image's Dockerfile in the question?  (Other common causes are a server configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0, or running Docker Toolbox or another VM-oriented Docker installation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to connect inside the container?

If not, you may fight this other unrelated question (covering the outside container case) helpful:

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: inside the container

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `curl https://localhost:8080` try `curl host.docker.internal:8080`.

Comment: Worked for me with curl https://host.docker.internal:8080 inside of container