# Failed to connect to localhost inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, curl

When deploying docker container I have to start a server inside of it, and post some data from inside the container, using those bash commands (both inside the same Docker container):

```
screen -dmS screen-name java -jar app.jar

curl -X POST --data-binary "path/to/data" http://127.0.0.1:8082/url/path
```

When I test bash commands locally -- everything works as suggested.
But inside the container I get this error:

```
#15 431.2 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8082: Connection refused
```

I found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580259/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-10001-connection-refused-docker), but there was no solution

Comment: What's inside the container?  What is the single process that's running in the container?  Where are you typing these commands?

Comment: 1) Server-jar and some scripts
2) For the purpose of this question we can be sure that only this jar (there is nothing that deployed before)
3) Inside bash-scripts, that I'm execute in RUN command of Dockerfile

Comment: It seems unusual to me for `screen` to be installed in a container at all, much less to be part of a `RUN` directive?  Do you have a [mcve], including enough of the Dockerfile to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to *"talk"* to a server of some type you haven't specified which is running **inside the same container** and not on the docker host.

If so, you could try:

```
# Get container's IP address
IP=$(hostname -i | awk '{print $1}')

curl -X POST --data-binary "path/to/data" "http://${IP}:8082/url/path"
```

---

Here's the simplest example:

```
docker run -it alpine:latest                                         
/ # hostname -i
172.17.0.2
```

Comment: You rightly presumed the problem, but this doesn't help -- this command also gives me address 127.0.0.1

Comment: I think you are going to need to share a minimal `Dockerfile` and code that causes the problem, please.